# Where are Typescript interfaces normally stored in an application?

Tags: typescript

I have an application that I coded like this:

```
// File util.ts
class Util  { 
   // ....
   // ...
}
export = Util; 

// File base.ts
import Util = require('../../Utils/util'); 
class AdminBase extends Util {
    .... 
    isSelectedValue (data: IElement) {
        var title = data.text;
        var valueString = data.val.toString();
        it('Check for ' + data.text, function () {
            expect(element(by.id(data.id)).getAttribute("value")).toBe(valueString);
        });
    }
    ....
    ExamStatusId = {
        All: <IEnumElement>{
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: <IEnumElement>{
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
    ....
export = AdminBase; 

// File page.ts
class ExamPage extends AdminBase {
    ...
    ...
}
export = ExamPage;

// File test.ts
import ExamPage = require('./page'); 
var page = new ExamPage();
describe('Admin Exam Page test', function () {
   page.isSelectedValue(page.ExamStatusId.All);
});
```

Here's the interface that I have:

```
interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
```

Can someone tell me in a Typescript application such as this. Where should I put the interface file? Are interfaces stored along with definitions and if so then how would my application be able to reference them?

Comment: What language is that? Please add a tag.

Comment: Typescript tag has already been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using *external modules* I recommend creating a `globals.ts` file that has no `export` statement at the *top level* which will contain all your `interface` declarations so you don't need to keep doing an `import` just to get the interface information.

You would reference this `globals.ts` file with a standard `reference` tag i.e.

```
/// <reference path="../globals.ts"/>
```

**BTW** grunt-ts (https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts) can generate this reference tag for you if you have the following code in your typescript file:

```
///ts:ref=globals
```

Answer (score 4):

The *Typescript* interfaces can be placed anywhere, as you like. Any place from which these defintions are available is ok.

But these are really just *Typescript* one... because they are **design time feature**. They are not converted/compiled into any JavaScript code.

So, if it make sense, place them in separate file or directly in the same where the implementation is. There is no "must" rule...

*I.e. place them in a one file and observe what happens after compilation... that `js` file will be (almost) empty*

Answer (score 1):

I always just put my interfaces in the same file as the actual implementation, unless I have two or more implementations. In that case I have a "feature name" folder with Implementations and Interfaces subfolders.

When it is in the same file I put it at the top like so (this happens to be something like an angular service):

```
module Project.Section.Feature.Service{
   export interface IFeatureService{
       method():void;
       propertyOne: number;
   }

   export class FeatureService implements IFeatureService{
       method(){
           //do stuff
       }

       propertyOne = 0;
   }
}
```

As Radim Köhler's answer states, in the end it is quite arbitrary because it only matters to the compiler at compile time. At run time, you will only have the JS from the implementation.

For multiple implementations, I just put Interface in the same module so I can easily reference it. Like so:

```
//file one
module Project.Section.Feature.Service{
   export interface IFeatureService{
       method():void;
       propertyOne: number;
   }
}

//file two
module Project.Section.Feature.Service{
    export class FeatureService implements IFeatureService{
       method(){
           //do stuff
       }

       propertyOne = 0;
   }

}
```

This makes your code look like they are in the same namespace, so you don't have to have something like `implements Interfaces.IFeatureService` decorating your class.

The compiler and intellisense will keep track of all your *.ts files and understands what you are attempting to do, and give you all that strongly typed goodness (at least in Visual Studio).

Comment: So in this case would you suggest (can I) just place the Interface description before the Class ?  When you have your feature name folder then how are those interfaces referenced?  How does the code know about them, do you have to include them?  Thanks